# Double Scroll bars messing up lazy load behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, lazy-loading

I have two vertical Scrollbars, which are placed parallely to each other. The thing is that I'm trying to implement a lazy load to my web page, but it isn't behaving as expected.

I want to fire the lazy load event only when the inner scrollbar is actuated, actually it's being fired when the outer scrollbar is actuated.

I'll post below a code snippet (extracted from internet, not the real one) that behave a bit as I mentioned before. Let's imagine I want to display the scrollbar coords only when the inner scroll is actuated. I hope I have explained myself well

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => console.log(scrollY))
```

```css
html{height:5000px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scrollTop` property on the element that has the scroll.

Having said that, I would like to mention the [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API that monitors elements (that you specify) and fire an event when an element intersects another element (ie. when an element enters the viewport for example). It is more performant and you have better control over what should happen and when it should happen.

```js
const inner = document.getElementById("inner");

inner.addEventListener("scroll", event => console.log(inner.scrollTop));
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.inner {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-inline: auto;
  margin-top: 25vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner" class="inner">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit quasi labore veniam blanditiis perferendis ex repellendus. Consectetur error veritatis maxime ut quisquam odio iste fugiat, vel, dicta iure vero mollitia? Doloribus consequuntur eos
    veritatis sunt corrupti maiores alias perferendis asperiores consequatur, illo, minus aut esse placeat quam itaque quos inventore ipsa eum aperiam? Optio, labore perspiciatis! Possimus sed ipsum suscipit vel perferendis porro quaerat consequuntur.
    Totam quibusdam sit quas quae delectus doloremque consequatur minima? Adipisci facere quam ipsum ex sed alias molestiae temporibus! Voluptatum cum quae molestiae, ut fuga sint atque nam placeat dolores tenetur. Doloribus odit placeat ea corrupti!
  </p>
</div>
```